# Python regex on multiple src to destination

Tags: python, regex, file

I have been reading through thousands of posts trying to find best solution. 
I apologize if the nature of this question has been asked multiple times before.

I have a file that I put placeholders in. The file is 200 lines and in this file there is a section where I have `propertyNames` and corresponding `propertyValues`. The `propertyValues` are placeholders that I want to find and substitute actual values with.
I think I will use `fileinput` and `re` modules to do this, but I do not want to have to parse line by line multiple times to fill in multiple `propertyValues`. Instead I was thinking it would be more efficient to have multiple strings I search for and its corresponding replacement text and while its scanning through lines if it finds any instance it replaces with its corresponding replacement.
What would be the best way to do this? Can it be done in a simple way with `fileinput` and `re`?

Comment: What have you try so far? Why not simply generate the whole file once you have the values you want to put in it, or append newly created values at the end of the file? Knowing what file format you need to handle would help a lot. Doing what you want without any parsing lead you pretty much to the only option, generate the file when you are ready to...

Comment: 200 lines is not so bad. You can definitely get away with reading the whole file into memory and doing all of your processing. Also, `re.sub` is what you are probably looking for. Instead of a replacement string, you can pass a callback to `re.sub`. Inside of that callback, you could determine which value to replace the matched placeholder with.

Answer (score 0):

I would use jinja for that. It's a templating engine that allows you to do that and much more (like having for loops inside your templates, and so on).

Take a look at: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/

Of course, this would need to change the input file format. If you are allowed to do that, I think this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question there are two cases

**First:** Search and replace line by line

```
$place_holders=[]

find_and_replace():
    for $line in $file:
        for $text in $line:
            if $text == "Target text":
                $place_holders.add($text.get_place_holder)

        if place_holders.size != 0:
            for $place_holder in $place_holders:
                replace "New text" at position $place_holder
            $place_holders=[]
```

**Second:** Search all lines then replace

```
find_and_replace():
    for $line in $file:
        for $text in $line
            if $text == "Target text":
                $place_holders.add($text.get_place_holder)

if $place_holders.size != 0:
    for $place_holder in $place_holders:
        replace "New text" at position $place_holder
    $place_holders=[]
```

What is difference between codes above?

Yes, just how many times you ask the question "`place_holders` list is empty or not?" the **first** case asks `file.number_of_line` times meanwhile the **second** case ask only one time. I think this should have a very small significant to speed of regex.

**Note** the code above is just simple demonstration of scenerio in your problem, there is no guarantee that regex engine will work in this way.

**BUT**

If you want the another way to optimize a speed of your program, I suggest

1. Do parallel computing,
2. Use any regex engine which provide JIT compilation (In case that you have a complex regex).